# Vue and Vuetify separating js html and css

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am not a fan of combining my html, css, and js into a single vue file, so instead I structure my Vue components this way:

```
├── Calendar
│   ├── Calendar.css
│   ├── Calendar.html
│   ├── Calendar.js
│   └── index.vue
```

In index.vue I reference these individual files as such:

```html
<template src="Calendar.html"></template>
<script src="Calendar.js"></script>
<style lang="css" src="Calendar.css"></style>
```

This has always worked for me and been my prefered way of organizing the code. I have just run into an issue, however, with Vuetify. After registering the plugin globally, I find that many of the components, including `<v-card>` give the unknown component error unless I place all the files into a single Vue component. Is the way I am doing things a bad practice, or will it simply not work with the vuetify way of doing things?

Comment: Can you give an example component where you get this error with this structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @marsnebulasoup and his comment, I realized I couldn't reproduce the issue using any prebuilt code sandboxes with vuex configured so it must have to do with my specific configuration. I was able to work it out by uninstalling and reinstalling vuetify. After I did that everything worked, but it created a new vuetify plugin file. Once I pointed it back to the configuration I was using previously, it broke again. I realized that the configuration I was using was using this import

`import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib/framework"`

But the default configuration from vuetify was using

`import Vuetify from "vuetify"`

Once I changed the custom import to match the default import everything worked again. I am using a template that had vuetify built in so I didn't immediately notice the configuration difference, having never installed vuetify on my own before. I still don't know why that makes a difference, but it does.